# Combining CSV Files into one master file and keep the file name in the Column 2

Tags: excel, csv, cmd, vba

I have many CSV. files that I want to combine into one big one, further to that, I also need to keep the File Name in Column 2.

Contents of my CSV file

File Name ABNK102455

```
Column A
12/215425
12/125485
12/215435
```

File Name ABNK102456

```
Column A
12/215425
12/125485
12/215435
```

Result

Combined.CSV

```
Column A
12/215425   ABNK102455
12/125485   ABNK102455
12/215435   ABNK102455
12/215425   ABNK102456
12/125485   ABNK102456
12/215435   ABNK102456
```

Is this possible, and How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "mask=q*.csv"
SET "headerlinegenerated="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /b "%sourcedir%\%mask%"') DO (
  SET "headerline="
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%m IN ("%sourcedir%\%%~nxa") DO (
   IF NOT DEFINED headerlinegenerated SET "headerlinegenerated=Y"&ECHO %%m
   IF DEFINED headerline ECHO %%m %%~na
   SET headerline=Y
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a files named `q26135599-1.csv` and `q26135599-2.csv` containing your data for my testing. You would need to adjust the setting of `mask` to suit.

Produces newfile.txt

Best not to try to create `newfile.txt` as a `.csv` within your source directory, unless you're really sure that it won't be included in `%mask%`.

Comment: nice way to do it on the command line ... didn't think about that ... +1

Comment: Hi @Magoo, thank you so much for the help, how would I run this?? looking at this its done in CMD, Im not very good with DOS.

Comment: Copy and paste to `filenameofyourchoosing.bat`. Then simply run `filenameofyourchoosing` from a `cmd` prompt. If you store the `.bat` on your `path`, then it doesn't matter which directory you run it from. Or you could establish a "shortcut" to the `.bat` file and run it from your desktop by clicking it.

Comment: Hi @Magoo, thank you, i did do that, and the new file is empty, I think im doing something wrong. the folder with all the .CSV is on my C: in a folder called ssonly.

Comment: In that case, you should use the lines `SET "sourcedir=c:\ssonly"` and `SET "mask=*.csv"` in place of the similar `SET "sourcedir=..."` and `SET "mask=..."` as documented. The setting of `sourcedir` is simply the directoryname in which you want the directory-scan to occur, and `mask` allows a filematch-mask to be assigned. Doing it this way rather than coding the names in directly makes it easy to change and adapt. Note that im **my** system, to allow me to test the procedure, I assigned `U:\sourcedir` and `Q*.csv` respectively.

Comment: WOW @Magoo, that is unreal, Thank you so much!!!! your a champ!!! you saved my life, I was thinking i was going to manually do this 2523 time.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going ....

```
Sub Test()
Dim Idx As Long
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim FileName As String

    RowNum = 1
    Set TargetRange = ActiveSheet.[A1]

    ' File selection loop
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        ' use .Filters.Add ... to present only .txt, .csv files etc.
        .Show

        ' File processing loop
        For Idx = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            ' here you get each file name inc. full path ... one by one
            FileName = .SelectedItems(Idx)

            ' isolate filename
            ' open file

            ' while not end of file
            '     read from file line by line into a string variable
            '     place string into TargetRange(RowNum, 1)
            '     place filename into TargetRange(RowNum, 2)
            '     increment RowNuM

        Next Idx
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @MikeD, Thank you for this VB Code, will also see if I can get this going