# Copy content from multiple .xls files into one file and file name in last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have many .xls, .csv and/or .xlsx files which I need to merge into one large file. The structure of the files is always the same. For example, file "one" looks like:

```
col A
123
456
789
```

but has eight columns and file "two", also with eight columns, looks like:

```
col A
1011
1213
1415
```

For the moment, I want to copy all sheets and the file name, too, such that the result should be like:

```
col A   filename
123       one
456       one
789       one
1011      two
1213      two
1415      two
```

I would like to use VBA to solve this. I have found [this unfinished solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135599/combining-csv-files-into-one-master-file-and-keep-the-file-name-in-the-column-2) and some other VBA parts like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/combine-xls-and-xlsx-files-into-one/6a2b0e9c-0136-45cb-90e6-a49123e7453e) but was not able to insert the file name. There is also a solution to a more [complicated/specific](https://superuser.com/questions/304899/how-can-i-merge-hundreds-of-excel-spreadsheet-files) problem but I haven't figured out how to boil the code down to my simpler problem.

Comment: Looks like a basic VBA exercise. Please try to code it, show your code and many people will be ready to help you take it to a good end.

Comment: Are all of the files in one folder? And, are these the only files in that folder?

Comment: Yes, all files are in one folder, and there are no other files in the folder

Comment: @ A.S.H : I did not post my sample code because it was from the links provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

Create a new BLANK workbook and place these procedures in a standard code module. Save this new file and then run `Fuji()`.

```
Public Sub Fuji()
    Dim c&, sPath$, sFile$, v, wsReport As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    sPath = "c:\tmp\fiji\"  '<-- Edit source file folder and INCLUDE final backslash.
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set wsReport = ActiveSheet
    wsReport.Name = "Merged"
    DoEvents
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.*")
    SetExcelEnvironment 1
    Do
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing... " & sPath & sFile
        With Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
            With .Worksheets(1)
                v = .Range(.[a1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp))
                With wsReport.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(v))
                    .Value = v
                    .Offset(, 1) = sFile
                End With
            End With
            .Close 0
        End With
        sFile = Dir
    Loop Until sFile = ""
    With wsReport
        .Rows(1).Delete
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    SetExcelEnvironment 0
End Sub

Private Sub SetExcelEnvironment(bProcessing As Boolean)
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = Not bProcessing
        .ScreenUpdating = Not bProcessing
        .StatusBar = ""
        .DisplayStatusBar = bProcessing
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes that only column A will be collected to the report file and that the name of the source file will be reported in column B.

Note: this assumes that all of the files are in the same folder and that you edit the location of that source folder on the sPath line near the top of the `Fuji()` routine.

Note: this assumes that the source folder ONLY contains files that will be culled (and understood by Excel) with this procedure.

Note: this assumes that all source file data will come from the first sheet.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated requirement of multiple columns of data, please use this version:

```
Public Sub Fuji()
    Dim c&, sPath$, sFile$, v, wsReport As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    sPath = "c:\tmp\fiji\"  '<-- Edit this and INCLUDE final backslash.
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.*")
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set wsReport = ActiveSheet
    wsReport.Name = "Merged"
    DoEvents
    SetExcelEnvironment 1
    Do
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing... " & sPath & sFile
        With Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
            With .Worksheets(1)
                v = .[a1].CurrentRegion.Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row)
                With wsReport.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2))
                    .Value = v
                    .Offset(, UBound(v, 2)).Resize(, 1) = sFile
                End With
            End With
            .Close 0
        End With
        sFile = Dir
    Loop Until sFile = ""
    With wsReport
        .Rows(1).Delete
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    SetExcelEnvironment 0
End Sub

Private Sub SetExcelEnvironment(bProcessing As Boolean)
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = Not bProcessing
        .ScreenUpdating = Not bProcessing
        .StatusBar = ""
        .DisplayStatusBar = bProcessing
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, now if you tell me how to apply this to 8 columns (all files have the same columns, col A, col B, col C,...) you are really my hero!

Comment: Yikes. You were pretty clear about it being column A for the data and column B for the file name. I'll need to rework it now. Please accept it though because it answers you specific question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was presenting a mini-example and thought it would be easy to rescale it to more columns...

Comment: Excellent work, thank you! I am sure this post will be helpful to others, too!